# Git, порядок коммитов разных веток после слияния

Tags: git, git-merge, commit

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какому критерию сортируются коммиты разных веток после слияния?

Comment: В смысле сортируются? `merge` ведь объединяет только "концы" веток, коммиты остаются в двух отдельных цепочках. Какой-нибудь `git log --graph --all` сортирует по дате, так же как и до слияния.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, благодарю.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, на самом деле можно варьировать порядок вывода изменений в командах типа `git log`, так что некоторая доля *сортировки* тут присутствует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ветка в программе *git* — это (плавающий) указатель на коммит.

говорить о «сортировке» коммитов можно разве что в контексте их отображения (например, командой *log*).

по умолчанию они отображаются в порядке уменьшения времени создания коммита. даже если дерево коммитов имеет разветвления:

```
a - b - d - f
  \ c - e /
```

(здесь `f` — это «коммит слияния, а создавались коммиты последовательно: `a`, затем `b`, затем `c` и т.д.) отображаться оно будет примерно так:

```
$ git log --oneline
6094edb (HEAD -> master) f - Merge branch 'v2' into master
a4db3bb (v2) e
13a8616 d
d9058d5 c
fd451ee b
5f24254 a
```

отобразить в виде дерева можно с помощью опции `--graph`:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
*   6094edb (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'v2' into master
|\  
| * a4db3bb (v2) e
| * d9058d5 c
* | 13a8616 d
* | fd451ee b
|/  
* 5f24254 a
```